# How to open a file from a mounted drive (nas in home network) in postgresql and win 11?

Tags: postgresql, copy, mounted-volumes

I want to open a csv file with the copy command. The file is on a sahred drive in home network and connected in win as w: . Over DBeaver from the sql command to copy the csv i get the error - No such file or directory. SQL command not find the mounted drive. Is there a workaround ?

The drive is on \\192.168.178.99 - in win is mounted as z:. Under windows 11 and in dos client i can reach it over z:.

sql command: COPY (select * from test_tab) TO 'z:\tmp\test_to_copy_something.csv' WITH CSV;

error: SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open file 'z:\tmp\test_to_copy_2021-01.csv' for writing: No such file or directory

Comment: Please post full path name to file, the complete copy statement and the complete error message - as text, **no images**. Besides DBeaver also run the same same sequence in psql command line.

Comment: i added the copy statement